# Can an ssl certificate be modified?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl

Is there any way to modify a ssl certificate? I don't want to change any of sections relating to authentication, only some of the surrounding data, e.g. `Issuer` or `X509v3 Key Usage`. Is there any tool that will take an existing certificate and the new value for a field, and output an identical certificate with the modification made? Or is the only solution to generate a new certificate from scratch and include the modifications there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need a new certificate.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956959/how-to-change-issuer-name-in-certificate-i-have-used-keytool